# Same membership table for different asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have a asp.net website which has form authentication, I have to develop another website which will access the same database for login.

I believe I have to create application ID before going further.

Or when I execute the below statement will create the application id in the aspnet_membership table?

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser("UserName", "password", "email@xyz.com");
```

What could be the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

You should set it in the Web.config file:

See also [ScottGu's blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx)

So in one website, you set the `applicationName` as "App1" in the Web.config, and in the other one you'll name it "App2".